# cs50 pset8 Finance register generating 500 internal server error

Tags: finance, cs50

I can't seem to get a user registered without the 500 error code. The login and register forms work correctly and check for username/password, but when I click on REGISTER button, I get the error message. The register code in application.py is similar to the login code except for my hash. Tried two different hash code formats. Can you see anything that may be causing this?

@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
"""Register user"""

```
# forget any user_id
session.clear()

if request.method == "POST":

    # ensure username was submitted
    if not request.form.get("username"):
        return apology("enter username", 400)

    # ensure password was submitted
    elif not request.form.get("password"):
        return apology("enter password", 400)

    # ensure confirm_password was submitted
    elif not request.form.get("confirm_password"):
        return apology("enter confirm_password", 400)

    # ensure there is a match
    elif request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("confirm_password"):
        return apology("password and confirm_password must match", 400)

    # hash password and insert new user
    new_user = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash)  VALUES(:username, :hash)", username = request.form.get("username"), hash=hash)
```

#hash = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password")))

```
    if new_user is None:
         return apology("registration key error", 400)
    
    # Remember which user has logged in
    session["user_id"] = new_user
    
    return redirect("/")

else:
    return render_template("register.html")
```

Comment: Have a look at the traceback in the `flask run` terminal, it will tell what line is causing the problem.

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1967, in finalize_request
   response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2097, in make_response
    "The view function did not return a valid response. The"
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.INFO:werkzeug:192.168.100.165 - - [24/Jul/2020 18:58:50] "GET /register HTTP/1.0" 500 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.100.165 - - [24/Jul/2020 18:58:50] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -

Comment: Above are the last few lines of the traceback. Couldn't fit it all here. Not sure what it means.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the entire register route. The problem is coming in the unseen code (assuming this is the POST block),  from a GET request, based on this `"GET /register HTTP/1.0" 500 - `. Or look over the code to see where a `return` is missing, based on this `he function either returned None or ended without a return statement.`.

Comment: I just added the entire register route. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The code, assuming it is continuous, gives an error from this line:

```
   new_user = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash)  VALUES(:username, :hash)", username = request.form.get("username"), hash=hash)
```

because `hash` is not defined. This line

```
#hash = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password")))
```

would do that if it wasn't commented and

1. was before the `db.execute`
2. didn't have an extra close paren (`')`) that causes a syntax error

Comment: Thank you, I defined hash and fixed the syntax, but it didn't change the error from occurring. Still trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: Clarify please "_The login and register forms work correctly and check for username/password, but when I click on REGISTER button, I get the error message._" How can the register form "work" if clicking on REGISTER gives an error?

Comment: I now have the code so that when I type flask run, it goes to the login page. I can enter a username/password and when I click on LOGIN button, it goes to the page to select QUOTE, BUY, SELL, HISTORY but I get an internal server error as well.  Same happens for register. I can register a user, and it goes to the same page to select my options (II even get the message, REGISTRATION SUCCESSFUL), but that internal server error shows up again.

Comment: All routes lead to `index`, so that is likely where the problem lies.